# Delete selected row in Ant design table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to pass selected row id to handleDelete() when Button is pressed. For some reason its sending id's of all objects inside array. But I **only want to capture selected row** id and send it to handleDelete function.

```
 const columns = [
    
 {
      title: 'Action',
      key: 'action',
      sorter: true,
      render: (text, row) => (
        <Space size="middle">
           <Button onClick = {handleDelete(row.id)} type="text"> Delete </Button>
                 </Space>
      ),
    },
]
```

My table component

```
<Table
        {...tableProps}
        pagination={{
          position: [top, bottom],
        }}
        columns={tableColumns}
        dataSource={hasData ? data : []}
        scroll={scroll}
      />
```

Function to recieve id : ( I am sending the ID's but its logging all the ID's )

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
    console.log(id)

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing `handleDelete(row.id)` to `onClick` causes `handleDelete` to be called for each item during render time of the component.

Change the callback of `onClick` event handler for delete button, in a way that an arrow function returns `handleDelete`:

```
<Button onClick = {() => handleDelete(row.id)} type="text"> 
   Delete 
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write your delete function like this

```js
const handleDelete = (id) => () => {
   console.log(id)
}
 
 // Usage
const columns = [   
 {
      title: 'Action',
      key: 'action',
      sorter: true,
      render: (text, row) => (
        <Space size="middle">
           <Button onClick={handleDelete(row.id)} type="text"> Delete </Button>
                 </Space>
      ),
 },
]
```

and another way, use `bind` like this:

```js
const handleDelete = (id) => {
  console.log(id)
}

// usage

 const columns = [
 {
      title: 'Action',
      key: 'action',
      sorter: true,
      render: (text, row) => (
        <Space size="middle">
           <Button onClick={handleDelete.bind(this,row.id)} type="text"> Delete </Button>
                 </Space>
      ),
    },
]
```

One option remaining, use dataset attribiutes:

```js
    const handleDelete = (e) => {
      console.log(e.target.dataset.id)
    }

    // usage

     const columns = [
     {
          title: 'Action',
          key: 'action',
          sorter: true,
          render: (text, row) => (
            <Space size="middle">
               <Button data-id={row.id} onClick={handleDelete} type="text"> Delete </Button>
                     </Space>
          ),
        },
    ]
```